# How do I count(distinct [columnname]) where TWO conditions are met in different rows of the same column?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get a count of the `AccountNumbers` in all cases `where` their in column `InterestType` they fall under `Website` AND `Phone` in some other row.

Right now I have the following Query:

```
    SELECT
    count(distinct c.[AccountNumber]) AS [TriangleSize]
    FROM table
    WHERE [InterestType] = 'Web'
```

I need to make this query only where a given `AccountNumber` only counts if it has `InterestType` 'Web' somewhere AND `InterestType` 'Phone' somewhere.

**Example:**

```
AccountNumber    InterestType
001              Web
001              Phone
002              Web
002              Catalog
002              Mail
003              Phone
004              Phone
004              Web
```

If these were the lines in the database, my ideal query would return:

```
[TriangleSize]
2
```

Comment: tag the database being used

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T1.AccountNumber)
FROM
    My_Table T1
INNER JOIN My_Table T2 ON
    T2.AccountNumber = T1.AccountNumber AND
    T2.InterestType = 'Web'
WHERE
    T1.InterestType = 'Phone'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the account numbers:

```
SELECT c.[AccountNumber]
FROM table c
WHERE [InterestType] IN ('Web', 'Phone')
GROUP BY c.[AccountNumber]
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

If you want to count them, use a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT c.[AccountNumber]
      FROM table c
      WHERE [InterestType] IN ('Web', 'Phone')
      GROUP BY c.[AccountNumber]
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
     ) a;
```

Or, what is possibly the most efficient version:

```
select count(*)
from table c
where InterestType = 'Web' and
      exists (select 1
              from table c2
              where c2.AccountNumber = c.AccountNumber and
                    c2.InterestType = 'Phone'
             );
```

This is nice because there is no `count(distinct)` because there should be no duplicates (unless interest types can be duplicated for a given account).

Comment: This is almost working but I think there is a DISTINCT missing somewhere. It's just totally the numbers from 'Phone' and 'Web'

Comment: @doomsy . . . The second two should be counting the number of accounts that meet your condition (both web and phone).  Isn't that what you want?